# How to preserve the order of terms or the characters in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am doing an Elasticsearch query to respond to this requirements:

1. Fuzzy matching on some fields
2. Exact match must have the highest score (only in an *exact_keyword* field)
3. Preserve the order of terms or characters, e.g., if the search query is "Basic Data Science" -> The result must be in this order ['Basic Data Science', 'Data Science: Basic', ...]

I use this Elasticsearch query. The idea is trying to boost the **match_bool_prefix** and **span_first** to preserve the order. Secondary is the fuzzy matching.

```
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "service": <STRING_OF_SERVICE_NAME>
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "model": <STRING_OF_MODEL_NAME>
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_bool_prefix": {
            "keyword_1": {
              "query": <SEARCH QUERY>,
              "boost": 30
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "span_first": {
            "match": {
              "span_multi": {
                "match": {
                  "fuzzy": {
                    "keyword_1": {
                      "value": <SEARCH QUERY>,
                      "boost": 20
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "end": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "span_first": {
            "match": {
              "span_multi": {
                "match": {
                  "prefix": {
                    "keyword_1": {
                      "value": <SEARCH QUERY>,
                      "boost": 10
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "end": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "span_first": {
            "match": {
              "span_multi": {
                "match": {
                  "fuzzy": {
                    "keyword_1": {
                      "value": <SEARCH QUERY>,
                      "boost": 0.05
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "end": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "keyword_1^3",
              "keyword_2^2",
              "keyword_3^0.5"
            ],
            "query": <SEARCH QUERY>,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "keyword_1^30",
              "keyword_2^20",
              "keyword_3^5",
              "exact_keyword^100",
              "entity_id^5"
            ],
            "query": <SEARCH QUERY>
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```

However, my result is that it does not always preserve the order. For example, for the search query = *'John Provi'* the result from the Elasticsearch's highlight will be

1.

```
"_highlight": {
                    "keyword3": [
                        "<em>John</em>"
                    ],
                    "keyword1": [
                        "<em>John</em>"
                    ]
```

2. 

```
"_highlight": {
                    "keyword3": [
                        "<em>John</em> John John John John John John"
                    ],
                    "keyword1": [
                        "<em>John</em> John John John John John John"
                    ]
```

3. This is the one that need to show first

```
"highlight": {
          "keyword_1": [
            "<em>John</em> <em>Provider</em>"
          ]
```

As you can see, the **"John Provider"** is shown in the 3rd place. For more information, I have around 700 contents in this scenaraio. However, if testing this query in my local environment, which have around 10 contents, it generates correct result with the correct order. I don't understand why this happens.

This is my Elasticsearch mapping

```
es_mappings = {
    "properties": {
        "keyword_1": {"type": "text",
                      "analyzer": "thai_analyzer"
                      },
        "keyword_2": {"type": "text",
                      "analyzer": "thai_analyzer"
                      },
        "keyword_3": {"type": "text",
                      "analyzer": "thai_analyzer"
                      },
        "exact_keyword": {"type": "keyword"},
        "service": {"type": "keyword"},
        "model": {"type": "keyword"},
        "entity_id": {"type": "keyword"}

    }
}
```

This is the Elasticsearch analyzer

```
es_settings = {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "thai_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "thai",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                    "trim",
                    "decimal_digit"
                ],
                "char_filter": [
                    "html_strip"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you